# Do desultory, result, consult share the same root?

Tags: etymology

In *desultory, result, consult*, do *sult* all mean jump and leap?

I searched etymonline, which gives different interpretation, especially in consult, sult seems to mean gather together. But I hope the three words have the same root with the same meaning.

Comment: Is "desult" a neologism?  I can't find it in [Oxford Dictionaries.](http://oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=desult)  I am familiar with the term [desultory](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/desultory?q=desultory) but this is the first time I have encountered [desult.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=desult)

Comment: According to [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/desultory?q=desultory) the origin of desultory is "late 16th century (also in the literal sense 'skipping about'): from Latin desultorius 'superficial' (literally 'relating to a vaulter'), from desultor 'vaulter', from the verb desilire"

Comment: @Lumberjack: Oh, I must be wrong. I looked at desultory, but I thought about desult.

Comment: ‘Consult’ does not fit (it is indeed from a root meaning ‘take, gather’, which is the same root that underlies the English verb ‘sell’), but the three others are all derived from the root _*sel-_ ‘jump, leap’. Since etymonline.com is considered General Reference, though, this is off-topic.

Comment: PIE roots isn't off-topic, though. They're hard to find online and useful to know. If you're really curious about etymology, a knowledge of the roots involved really clears things up. For instance, [_*sel-_](http://web.archive.org/web/20080630005527/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE450.html) in the 2000 edition of the [American Heritage Dictionary of Indo-European Roots](http://web.archive.org/web/20080628053511/http://www.bartleby.com/61/IEroots.html)

Comment: @JohnLawler: Thanks! What is PIE?

Comment: PIE stands for _Proto-Indo-European_, the name of the reconstructed language ancestral to most European, Iranian, and North Indic languages, including English, French, Russian, Latin, Sanskrit, and Greek. Details [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/3850/482). The dictionary list all the known roots and indicates all the English cognates of each, which are always surprising.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Thanks! By 'the dictionary", do you mean http://ahdictionary.com? How can I find etymology of a particular word there?

Comment: The dictionary of PIE roots is an appendix to the ahd. The one online is in a special "history of the web" archive from 2000 or so, and it's only the 2nd edition. There is now a new one and a new ahd. To find the etymology, buy the dictionary or subscribe online.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Thanks! Is there a dictionary that can give base, prefix, postfix, and root of a given word? (I think a dictionary of etymology may or may not provide root, base, prefix, postfix, but will provide origins of the words. Am I right?).

Comment: The AHD will do that. It uses a lot of abbreviations and you'll have to read the instructions carefully (there are a lot).

Comment: I don't care if it's off-topic but it does contribute to the knowledge base on ELU Q&A. Stet. :)

Comment: I used *stet* in a lighter vein. To an editor, *stet* means 'let it be/ let it stay/ let it remain/ do not delete.'

Comment: @JohnLawler +1. I wish I had seen earlier your post of Oct 13 '13 at 17:20!

Comment: Some other words with that same Latin leaping root: **insult** (something like *leap upon*), **exult** (*leap out*), **somersault** (*leap over*), **assault** (*leap at*). Also, per the OED a *desultor* was "a circus horse-leaper", which gives a picture of a much more energetic origin for *desultory* than I would have guessed based on contemporary usage.

Answer (score 3):

From a further exploration of etymonline:

- [desultory](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=desultory&searchmode=none) - eventually from Latin: "de- 'down' (see de-) + salire 'to jump, leap' "
- [result](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=result&searchmode=none) - related to [resilient](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=result&searchmode=none) "inclined to leap or spring back"
- [consult](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=consult) - "from com- 'with' (see com-) + *selere 'take, gather (the Senate) together,' "

So, desultory and result share a root (about jumping) from Latin, but consult/counsel does not (its root is about selection).